# swift 3.0 UIBarButtonItem action not work

Tags: swift3, uibarbuttonitem

```
let leftbarbuttonitem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Reset",style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(tapResetButton(_:)))

    func tapResetButton(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        count = 0
        numberLabel.text = "0"

    }
```

The action can't respond to the click event. I added the breakpoint then found that it even didn't go into the function. I have no idea what's wrong with my code. Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can declare `UIBarButton` Item inside `viewDidLoad()` method. Your actin method should get called. may be your missing something.

Comment: @Ashok Thank you for your answer. When I put the declare UIBarButtonItem inside viewDidLoad(),It works. But why can't I put the declare outside of the viewDidLoad()?

Comment: Try adding "lazy" before the button declaration. Worked for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Swift 3.0

***Declare UIBarButton inside ViewDidLoad()***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let logout: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.logOut))
}

func logOut() {
  print("LogOut")
}
```

***Declare UIBarButtonItem OutSide ViewDidLoad()***

```
var logout:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        logout = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.logOut))
}

func logOut() {
      print("LogOut")
}
```

***Declare Completely Outside viewDidLoad()***

```
lazy var logout: UIBarButtonItem = {
    UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.logOut))
}()
```

***Any Should work.***

*For your action parameter either you can specify `ViewController` name explicitly or you can just say `self`.*

```
action: #selector(self.logOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was wondering what was going on!! Do you have an idea why it is different for UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 5):

When I put the initialization of UIBarButtonItem out of the function viewDidLoad, the action can't respond. But when I put it into the function. It works. I don't know why. But the problem is resolved. If you know the reason. Please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Outside of a function, just out there in the body of the class, it doesn't get initialized because it is explicitly and implicitly referencing `self`. I think it's a bug that the compiler doesn't alert in those situations like it does in others. However, if you declare it as `lazy` it will work because by the time the property is accessed `self` is fully formed (see the lazy example above).